# No sound from headphones under ubuntu 13.10

Tags: audio, imac, headphones, unix

I have a fresh ubuntu on iMac. I have managed to set up the sound from the native speakers, however, there is still no sound from the headphones. I have disabled automute in alsamixer, but this didn't help. Does anyone know what to do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was found by adding a row of `options snd-hda-intel model=imac27_122` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` as explained [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12043359).

[image]